# How to prove $x=120^\circ$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

[image]

Let $ABC$ and $CDE$ be equilateral triangles.

How to prove that $x=120^\circ$?

Thank you.

Comment: use geogebra for better geometric constructions and etc....

Comment: @TahirImanov Nothing is wrong with his diagram.

Comment: If you call the point of intersection $P$, then it isn't always the case that $\angle APD = 120^\circ$; sometimes, the measure is $60^\circ$. Likewise with $\angle BPE$. (The threshold where things change is interesting.) However, it appears that *lines* $\overleftrightarrow{AP}$ and $\overleftrightarrow{DP}$ always form two $120^{\circ}$ angles (and two $60^\circ$ angles) at $P$. Neat little problem. Where did you find it?

Comment: If triangle CDE rotates about point C such that E lies on side BD, then we have angle DEC = 60 and angle BEC = 120. Clearly then angle AEC cannot be 120 degrees. Since we do not know anything about the orientation of triangle DEC with respect to triangle ABC, I think a piece of information is missing. Please correct me if wrong

Comment: I think the important point is that $ABPC$ and $CDEP$ would be cyclic, if that is the case.

Comment: In that case, opposite angles add up to 180, that changes it quite a bit.

Comment: @Sawarnik: Similar to imranfat's example. Rotate about $C$ until $D$ lies on $\overline{AC}$ (with $\overline{AC}$ separating $B$ and $E$). Then $\angle APD = 60^\circ$. The thresholds are the circumcircles of the triangles (which gets to your notion of the cyclic quadrilaterals): when, say, $D$ is *outside* the circumcircle of $\triangle ABC$, then $\angle APD  =120^\circ$; *inside*, $60^\circ$; when $D$ is *on* the circumcircle ... well ... it looks like $P$ and $D$ coincide (because of cyclic quads!), so the angle *as named* is undefined.

Comment: @Blue Oh, indeed :D

Comment: So in any case, we have to prove that $P$ is the intersection of the two circles ... which I think can be done easily? @Blue

Comment: @Sawarnik: Yes, it does appear that the $120^\circ$ (and/or $60^\circ$) property is logically equivalent to the intersection-of-circumcircles property.

Comment: @Blue And its quite easy to show that if the $L$ is the intersection, then $\angle BLE = \pi$ and  $\angle ADL = \pi$, and we are done? Yay.

Comment: Guys, I don't think it's easy to prove that the quqadrilaterals are cyclic, but I think this is easy to prove by angle chasing. Actually you can check my proof below.

Comment: This is one of the constructions of the [Fermat point](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1049367/139123) of a triangle (in this case the triangle $\Delta BCE$).

Answer (score 12):

**Hint:**

- Observe that $\triangle ACE$ is $\triangle BCD$ rotated by $60^\circ$ degrees.
- The above implies that $|\angle AXB| = 60^\circ$, where $X$ is the intersection of $AE$ and $BD$.

$\hspace{50pt}$[image: triangle rotation]

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: +1. Now I remember that I've seen this problem (and this solution) before. Maybe here, but I think elsewhere long ago, as well. My foggy memory is telling me that it's relatively "famous" (so I'm kicking myself for not remembering the trick right off! :).

Comment: @dtldarek. A picture says more than a thousand words! I was staring at it for some time, enjoying the colors, then all of the sudden, it "clicked" +1 Such a picture is worth a paining on the wall.

Comment: @Blue Indeed the problem is a well-known one, and since I've seen it many times. Yet, the first time I stumbled upon it and tried to solve, I've arrived at this particular solution (although the picture was far messier than the one above). It felt so nice (both the problem and its solution) that it was worth keeping in memory!

Comment: @imranfat Thank you, I appreciate your compliment!

Answer (score 2):

**NOTE**: This proof assumes that the segment $AE$ and $BD$ actually intersect at point $F$. Note that the $x=120^{\circ}$ holds when the the lines $AE$ and $BD$, instead of the segments intersect, but you can prove it in a simular fashion.

Let $F$ be the intersection point of $AE$ and $BD$ be $F$. Then from the quadrlaterial $FACD$ we have:

$$\angle AFD + \angle FDC + \angle DCA + \angle CBA = 360^{\circ}$$
$$120^{\circ} + 60^{\circ} - \angle EDF + 60^{\circ} + 60^{\circ} + \angle BCE + 60^{\circ} - \angle BAF = 360^{\circ}$$
$$\angle BCE = \angle BAF + \angle EDF \tag{1}$$

Now for the $\triangle ACE$ we have:

$$\angle EAC + \angle ACE + \angle CEA = 180^{\circ}$$
$$60^{\circ} - \angle BAF + 60^{\circ} + \angle BCE  + \angle CEA = 180^{\circ}$$

Nos using $(1)$ we have:

$$\angle CEA = 60^{\circ} - \angle EDF$$

Now using this we have:

$$\angle FED = 60^{\circ} + \angle CEA = 120^{\circ} - \angle EDF$$

Now using this from the $\triangle FED$ we have:

$$\angle DFE = 180^{\circ} - 120^{\circ} + \angle EDF - \angle EDF$$
$$\angle DFE = 60^{\circ}$$

Now at last:

$$\angle AFD = 180^{\circ} - \angle DFE = 180^{\circ} - 60^{\circ} = 120^{\circ}$$

Q.E.D.

Answer (score 1):

Let intersection of AE and BD be F. G is a point on AE, such that CG is parallel to BD. $\angle CBD = \angle BCG =\beta \Rightarrow \angle GCA =60^\circ - \beta $
Triangles ACE and BCD are equal, therefore $ \angle EAC = \beta $
Therefore $ \angle CGA =120^\circ $

> Triangles ACE and BCD are equal, because two sides and angle between them are equal.