# Proof: Two equilateral triangles

Tags: geometry, proof-writing

Given: Equilateral triangles $ABC$ and $CDE$

Prove: CM = CN

[image: Proof diagram]

I would assume I need to somehow use proportions, but I don't know where to start...

Comment: Look at the two smaller triangles BCM and NCE. Because the two larger triangles are equilateral, and I assume BE is straight, you know AB and NC are parallel, and CM and DE are parallel. That allows you to make some similar triangles. Try working from there.

Comment: Start with some basic facts about triangles, for instance we know that since triangles ABC and CDE are equilateral all internal angles must be $60^o$. From there you can find out angle $\angle ACD$ since straight lines have a $180^o$ angle. From there you should be able to discern some other angles from triangle ACE and BCD. As the @dtldarek points out they are similar triangles but rotated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Call $BC=x$ and $CE=y$. Because triangles $BCM$ and $BED$ are similar, we have 
$$
\frac{CM}{DE}=\frac{BC}{BE}\implies\frac{CM}{y}=\frac{x}{x+y}\implies CM=\frac{xy}{x+y}\cdot
$$
Similarly, triangles $ECN$ and $EBA$ are similar so $\frac{CN}{AB}=\frac{CE}{BE}\implies\frac{CN}{x}=\frac{y}{x+y}$ which gives $CN=xy/(x+y)$. The conclusion follows.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

- Observe that $\triangle BCD$ is $\triangle ACE$ rotated counter-clockwise by $60^\circ$ degrees.
- In particular, the same is true for $\triangle BCM$ and $\triangle ACN$.

There is a similar problem asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1169210/26306) (it's not the same, because in this problem we need $|\angle BCE|=180^\circ$).

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$