# If F is the Fermat point of triangle ABC, then what is the algebraic formula that gives minimum sum distance, i.e., FA+FB+FC=?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, maxima-minima

Fermat point (F) of a triangle is at the least distance from triangle vertices. If one of the vertex angle is greater than 120 degrees, then F is at that vertex, and minimum distance is equal to sum of the two short sides of triangle. Otherwise, F lies within triangle ABC and the sides AB/BC/CA subtend equal angle of 120 degrees at F. In this case, what is the algebraic formula for finding the minimum distance (in terms of triangle lengths a,b,c)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $ABC$ is a triangle with every angle being $\leq 120^\circ$ and $F$ is its Fermat-Torricelli point, we may introduce the points $A',B',C'$ given by the vertices of the equilateral triangles externally built on the sides of $ABC$. Then [we have that $(A,F,A'),(B,F,B'),(C,F,C')$ are collinear](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Generalization/fermat_point.shtml) and
$$ FA+FB+FC = AA' = BB' = CC'.\tag{1}$$
We may compute the (squared) length of $CC'$ through the cosine theorem:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} CC'^2 &=& a^2+c^2-2ac\cos\left(B+60^\circ\right) \\ &=&a^2+c^2-ac\cos(B)+\sqrt{3}\,ac\sin B\\&=&a^2+c^2-\frac{a^2+c^2-b^2}{2}+2\sqrt{3}\Delta\\&=&\color{red}{\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{2}+2\sqrt{3}\Delta}.\tag{2}\end{eqnarray*}$$
Here $\Delta=[ABC]$ can be found in terms of $a,b,c$ through Heron's formula.

Comment: What happens if one of measured-angles greater than $120^{\circ}$?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: then the minimum sum of distances is achieved at a vertex and it is trivial to compute (it is either $a+b,a+c$ or $b+c$).